# Show that $4(x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + 3) \geq 3(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)$ | Inequalities

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

I have the following problem involving inequalities.

Let $x, y, z > 0$ be real numbers. Show that the following is true:
$$4(x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + 3) \geq 3(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)$$
For which values of $x, y, z$ does equality hold?

At first I simplified as much as possible:
$$4x^3+4y^3+4z^3+12 \geq 3xyz + 3xy + 3xz + 3yz + 3x + 3y + 3z + 3$$

$$4x^3+4y^3+4z^3+9 \geq 3xyz + 3xy + 3xz + 3yz + 3x + 3y + 3z$$

But now I'm stuck. I know that the solution has something to do with geometric and arithmetic means, and that $\frac{a+b}{2}\geq\sqrt{ab}$. I just can't seem to see how to transform the inequality into something like that.

How would you solve such a question? I would greatly appreciate help!

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%244(x%5E3%2By%5E3%2Bz%5E3%2B3)%5Cgeq%203(x%2B1)(y%2B1)(z%2B1)%24&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [Kosovo Math Olympiad 2019](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1793972p11881588), which states this problem is from Kosovo MO $2019$ Grade $10$, Problem $2$.

Answer (score 3):

By Holder and AM-GM we obtain:$$4(x^3+y^3+z^3+3)=4(x^3+1)+4(y^3+1)+4(z^3+1)\geq$$
$$\geq(x+1)^3+(y+1)^3+(z+1)^3\geq3(x+1)(y+1)(z+1).$$

Answer (score 2):

Using Am_Gm inequality we see that

$$(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)\leq {(x+1)^3+(y+1)^3 +(z+1)^3\over 3}$$

so it is enough to check if $$(x+1)^3+(y+1)^3 +(z+1)^3 \leq 4(x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + 1+1+1)$$
is true (by means of elementary inequalities). Actualy it is again enough to check if $$(x+1)^3\leq 4x^3+4 = 4(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$ is true, i.e. if $$x^2+2x+1\leq 4x^2-4x+4$$ is true.

Answer (score -1):

Another way.

Let $x+y+z=3u$.

Thus, $$4(x^3+y^3+z^3+3)-3\prod_{cyc}(x+1)=$$$$=\sum_{cyc}(4x^3-xyz)-3(xy+xz+yz)-3(x+y+z)+9\geq$$
$$\frac{1}{3}(x+y+z)^3-(x+y+z)^2-3(x+y+z)+9=$$
$$=9(u^3-u^2-u+1)=9(u-1)^2(u+1)\geq0.$$

Comment: Can downvoter  explain we, why did you do it?

Comment: @Xander Henderson♦ Do you agree with this downvoting?  In my opinion, it's just destroying of the forum.

Answer (score -2):

Another way.

We need to prove that:
$$4(x^3+y^3+z^3)+9\geq3xyz+3(xy+xz+yz)+3(x+y+z)$$ and since by AM-GM
$$x^3+y^3+z^3\geq3xyz$$ and
$$\sum_{cyc}3xy\leq\sum_{cyc}(x^3+y^3+1)=2(x^3+y^3+z^3)+3,$$ it's enough to prove that:
$$x^3+y^3+z^3+6\geq3(x+y+z),$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^3+2)\geq\sum_{cyc}3\sqrt[3]{x^3\cdot1^2}=3(x+y+z).$$

Comment: Can downvoter  explain we, why did you do it?

Comment: @Xander Henderson♦ Do you agree with this downvoting?  In my opinion, it's just destroying of the forum.